# Intent android navigation multiple times

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, navigation, app-inventor

I have an app with a list of places (buttons). On buttonclick - android navigation should be open.

When I click first time - everything is fine - navigation app intents with specified lat,lon.

But when I click second time I get `App "Maps" An error has occurred`. Seems it's because navigation is already running.

I use `android.intent.action.VIEW` action and `google.navigation:q=[lat],[lon]` uri to intent

When I use `http://maps.google.com/maps?daddr=[lat],[lon]` uri - it works fine and intent maps app after each click again. But last one open maps instead of navigation.

I'm using **App Inventor** to create application, since I'm not familiar with Java

So is there way to intent android navigation multiple times (without manually closing)?

Thanks!

Comment: why don't you want to close the navigation app before opening it again? How to you switch back to the App Inventor app?

Comment: I can close manually, but it isn't not convenient. And Maps works fine on this principle, so i hope navigation can too.

Comment: I switch back using "multiple windows" button (on the bottom left)